# jquery - allow only negative, positive or decimal number validation

Tags: jquery

I need a javascript/jQuery routine that validates a string to allow only negative, positive or decimal numbers(ex. -1 or -41.02 or 20 or 2.20 or 10.05)

Comment: Is there a question? I don't see it.

Answer (score 4):

```
function validate(str){
   var fvalue = parseFloat(str);
   return !isNaN(fvalue) && fvalue != 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The regular expression given below solves the issue, it works for -ve decimal numbers.

^-?[0-9]{0,4}(.^-[0-9]{1,4})?$|^(100)(.^-[0]{1,4})?$

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to parse the value and see if you get a valid number.

You can also use regular expression for even more complex data type matching.

Try the following:

```
[-+]?([0-9]*\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+)
```

Also [look](http://www.regular-expressions.info/floatingpoint.html) here for further information.